# Sidekiq jobs disappering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a worker class that finds out who to send notifications and then creates notifications at which point `push` will send out the pushes.
But i have a problem with Sidekiq, that is when i do `SomeWorker.perform_in(5.seconds,someID, otherID)` it does show up in scheduled on the sidekiq dashboard. but  after 5 seconds the job disappears. the count for `processed` does not update nor it shows up in failed. Infact it just won't show up in any counter. Although sometimes the job is processed and i see the counter and logs and the push. but most of the times it just disappears to be found nowhere. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have an old Sidekiq process consuming the job.  Make sure all old processes are dead.

Comment: Probably makes sense. Will check it out and report shortly.

Comment: i have mulitple environments. but other than that there is no process for sidekiq. checked with `ps aux | grep sidekiq`